# Adjective for "not worth its price"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for something that is not worth its price? As in "This car is _____ (here goes the word)"; or "WWI was ____ the sufferings it caused to the world".

Comment: I think this is the first case of me coming across an instance where Dutch actually has a saying that English does not: "Het sop is de kool niet waard". Literally translated: "the stew is not worth [more than] the cabbage [that you use to make the stew with]".

Comment: Can you explain or elaborate on your second example? *Overpriced* doesn't sound right for that one, but it's not clear what you are trying to say with it.

Comment: @CanisLupus, "exorbitant" fits nicely in the second gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first example, there is simply ***overpriced***.

Your second example, however, is a little more challenging.

The best I could come up with is ***exorbitant***:

> ***[exorbitant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exorbitant)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> (of a price or amount charged) unreasonably high.
>   *‘some hotels charge exorbitant rates for phone calls’*

This would look like:

> The suffering caused by WWI was **exorbitant**.

or

> The cost of WWI, when you consider the suffering it caused, was **exorbitant**.

*[Reminder to myself: there is no "H" in exorbitant.]*

It's possible that ***disproportionate*** might work as well:

> ***[disproportionate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disproportionate)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Too large or too small in comparison with something else.
>   *‘people on lower incomes spend a disproportionate amount of their income on fuel’*
>   *‘persistent offenders were given sentences that were disproportionate to the offences they had committed’*

For your example, I would word it thusly:

> The cost of WWI was **disproportionate** to the suffering it caused.

You could also use ***unwarranted***:

> ***[unwarranted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unwarranted)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Not justified or authorized.
>   *‘I am sure your fears are unwarranted’*

as in:

> The suffering caused by WWI was **unwarranted**.

Answer (score 0):

For the first example, ***overpriced*** works.

Collins:

> **[overpriced](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overpriced)**
>   *adjective*
>   If you say that something is ***overpriced***, you mean that you think it costs much more than it should.
>   I went and had
>   an overpriced cup of coffee in the hotel cafeteria.
>   Any property
>   which does not sell within six weeks is overpriced.
>   COBUILD Advanced
>   English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

Comment: Well, if you think something is overpriced  you think something is priced more than it should be. I'm surprised Collins has muddled the distinction. If you go ahead a buy an overpriced item at the "sticker price" then you've overpaid.